# For loop from integer to decimal. How can it reach the decimal?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to have a for loop like this where the loop hits the 60.1875? If I start the range at .1875 it will work but I can't do that in this case.

```
for a from 1 to 60.1875

next a
```

Edit: This code needs to test options for running a print job on different size papers. We prefer to test whole numbers but we always need to test the outer limit of the press as well which is 60.1875.

Comment: And what values would it have in between 1 and 60.1875?

Comment: PLease explain more, why are you doing this etc? could find a better way to do things, this sounds messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the Step keyword, or the loop will jump in steps of 1 only and will ignore non-integer values.

for example:

```
Dim start As Decimal = 1
Dim finish As Decimal = 60.1875
For i=start to finish Step 0.0005
    If i = Int(i) Or i=start or i=finish Then
        '... do whatever
    End If
Next
```

Added the check for integers and outer bounds, but tbh this is cacked; there are better ways to do it!

Comment: Your idea is exactly what I wanted. Just curious, what better way do you suggest?

Comment: Well, for example you may find it more useful to have a defined list of values to use, maybe saved in a config or xml file, or database. It sounds to me like you have a few different configurations you want to use regularly, in which case this would be my preferred option as you can specify exactly the values to use. If your range is too large to practically include all values, you could specify a range maybe? SO your config could look like (1,2,3...60,60.1785) or (1-60,60.1875). Just a thought...

Comment: The range is dynamic and is entered by the user at run time.

Answer (score 0):

My sugggestion would be to do something like:

```
dim limit as decimal = 60.1875
for a = 1 to limit
    Console.WriteLine(a)
next a
Console.WriteLine(limit)
```

In your code of course replace `Console.WriteLine` with whatever code you are using.

My example above outputs the integers 1 to 60 and then 60.1875.

If you desperately need to run it in a single loop for some reason then you could use the above code to construct a `List(of decimal)` and then you could include everything in a single loop.